# How to close the search bar of TextEditor?

Tags: macbook-pro, text-editor, shortcut-menu

The search bar appears by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but how can I close it?

Comment: Did you mean TextEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the “TextEdit” application: You can close the search bar by hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> (or by clicking on the “Done” button).

Closing the search bar with <kbd>esc</kbd> works in many other applications as well, e.g. in Mail, Safari, or Xcode.